# Architecture advice for a website

Tags: asp.net, architecture, data-structures, class

I'm looking for a bit of advice with regards to the structure of an application I'm tasked with.

I need to have a series of webforms to store some data, most of the data is the same but each form would have some differeing data depending on the form used.

Would a base class then a series of classes inheriting from this for the specific data be best to use?

As in:
`order - compAOrder
       - compBOrder
       - compCOrder`

How about strucuting the database for this sort of application structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually went with a catch-all table with all the fields and different forms.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this kind of question is allways "It depends" but here is a possible solution:

- Program the system with a single web page for form data input.
- Use a query string value to identify which form it is.
- Hide and enable fields depending upon which form it is.
- Have a single data table that has all the possible fields.

Hope this helps

Shiraz